# Problem with org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, glassfish

I have problem with creating a persistence context using annotation. Where is the problem?

I've tried to use another versions

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
@Stateful
public class UserService {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPAUNIT", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;

public boolean saveUsr(User user){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        em.persist(user);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("User exists");
        return false;
    }
}
//other methods
}
```

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="JPAUNIT">
                <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>classes</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/points"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml

```
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

StackTrace

Exception while preparing the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)

**Updated:** 
Tried to use another versions as @SteveC said, but it didn't solve this

Added stack trace and pom.xml

Comment: Please provide the entire class definition for your `saveUsr` method. You can leave out the other methods for now

Comment: Also, is your deployment a WAR file or something else?

Comment: @SteveC yes, war. Using local glassfish 5

Comment: Can you confirm that the "hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar" is in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file?

Comment: @SteveC https://imgur.com/nucbGle

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is that both Glassfish 5 and Hibernate 3.7.x are JPA 2.2 implementations and you have that `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` dependency, which is both redundant and wrong. Glassfish 5 is also a Java EE 8 implementation so your `javaee-api-7.0` dependency should be updated (and made `<scope>provided</scope>` as well. Please add all of your dependencies to your question because you have many redundancies in the WAR. I suspect that the complete stack trace may tell us more too,

Comment: @SteveC please check

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @SteveC

**SOLVED**
Just created a new project with this dependencies

persistence.xml the same

src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml

pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Great! Only changes I would make for now are: change `javaee-api` to version 8.0 and add <scope>provided</scope>; remove `hibernate-entitymanager` - it is actually empty; remove `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` - these classes are already in the `javaee-api` dependency

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Had tried to troubleshoot by hand to no avail!